# how to develop a lync client using uccp api

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, lync-2010

I want to develop a lync client using the UCCP API SDK.

When I make a video call from external network to internal network using the sample application (UCCAVSAMPLE) from the UCCP API SDK it is giving the
`UCCMSSCR_MEDIA_CONNECTIVITY_FAILURE` error. Any modifications we have to do for the `application.call` is established media is not flowing. I have changed the DLLs (uccpapi and rftm). It was using older version (version 2) now m using version 4.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use the Lync client from the external network and trying to connect using the SIP protocol or you are trying to connect using another protocol like h.323